# display all scaled images in wordpress media library

Tags: wordpress, media

I scale a bunch of image sizes when I upload an image to the library. But there's only the uploaded image shown. How can I see all the created images?

and how can I give the rendered images an fixed extension  _1 _2 ...   not the imagesize.

regards

Comment: Check in the ftp where they're saving

Comment: the image creation is perfect, I want to see the image in the library. the user could choose the right image...  and it would be better to have names and not widhtxheight.